# Proof of the ‘second’ triangle inequality

Tags: solution-verification, alternative-proof

I am trying to prove the ‘second’ triangle inequality:
$$\Big||x|-|y|\Big| \leq |x-y|$$

My attempt:

---

Proof:
\begin{align} |x-y|^2 &= (x-y)^2 \\ &= x^2 - 2xy + y^2 \\ &\geq |x|^2 - 2|x||y| + |y|^2 \\ &= \left(\Big||x|-|y|\Big|\right)^2. \end{align}

Therefore $\implies |x-y| \geq \Big||x|-|y|\Big|$.

---

My questions are: Is this an acceptable proof?; and are there alternative proofs that are more efficient?

Comment: it seems good to me.

Answer (score 2):

Don’t work too hard: $$|x| - |y| \geq -|x - y|$$ is true because $|x| + |y - x| \geq |y|$, and $$|x| - |y| \leq |x - y|$$ because $|y| + |x - y| \geq |x|$. These are true because of the triangle inequality, hence the answer.

Comment: Please use $\LaTeX$.

Answer (score 0):

It is true in $\mathbb{R}$, but for $\mathbb{R}^n$, consider
$$|x| \le |x-y| +|y|.$$
Analogously,
$$|y|-|x| \le |x-y|.$$
or
\begin{align} |x-y|^2 &= \langle x-y,x-y\rangle \\ &= |x|^2 - 2\langle x, y \rangle + |y|^2 \\ &\geq |x|^2 - 2|x||y| + |y|^2 \\ &= \left(\Big||x|-|y|\Big|\right)^2. \end{align}

Comment: Note that this question is older. I doubt this will be of any use to the OP, although it may be of use to other users?

Comment: Isn't this exactly my proof in the question? Or are you saying this is the version for $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Yes, your proof is right and I'm saying that one usual notation for   the scalar product in $ \mathbb{R}^n$ is $\langle x, y \rangle $ you may also use $ x \cdot y$. If you do not do this people could think that you are proving the real case.